# Disable drag selection in JTable

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtable

**Problem**

I'd like to click on an unselected cell in a JTable and drag it, i. e. the table should be in drag mode. The problem is that the JTable has a mechanism that when you click on an unselected cell and drag, you actually aren't in drag mode, but in selection mode. Selection mode should only be possible via click and should be extendable via shift + click, not via dragging.

From what I've found the culprit is in BasicTableUI, but unfortunately everything there that's relevant is private.

**Question**

How can you prevent selection via dragging and be instantly in drag mode when you click on an unselected cell and drag it?

I searched, but none of the solutions I found were satisfactory. Or they were for older Java versions.

**Code**

Here's some code for the reproduction:

- Click on an unselected cell and drag the mouse. The cells will be selected.
- Click on a selectged cell and drag. The table is in drag mode.

The code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

import javax.swing.DropMode;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Object rowData[][] = { 
        { "a", "a", "a" }, 
        { "a", "a", "a" }, 
        { "a", "a", "a" }, 
        { "a", "a", "a" }, 
        { "a", "a", "a" }, 
        };

    Object columnNames[] = { "Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3" };
    final JTable table = new JTable( rowData, columnNames);

    table.setDragEnabled( true);
    table.setDropMode( DropMode.INSERT_ROWS);

    table.addMouseMotionListener( new MouseMotionAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {

        boolean selectionIsAdjusting = table.getSelectionModel().getValueIsAdjusting();

        if( selectionIsAdjusting) {
          System.out.println("selecting");
        } else {
          System.out.println("dragging");
        }

      }
    });

    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table);
    frame.add( scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize( 300, 150);
    frame.setVisible( true);

  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: `when you click on an empty cell and drag it?` Do you mean empty, no content cell (eg distinguish between empty string and other), or just drag on any cell? The code posted does not contain 'empty' cells.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I fixed it. It's an unselected cell. I want to click on an unselected cell and drag it.

Comment: It would be useful if you also updated the second sentence of your question.

Comment: @VGR: what do you mean?

Comment: There are at least two places in your question where you use the term “empty cell.”  If you mean an unselected cell, it would be far less confusing to readers if you changed the wording to “unselected cell.”

Comment: I changed it. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to directly call [TransferHandler#exportAsDrag(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#exportAsDrag-javax.swing.JComponent-java.awt.event.InputEvent-int-) method in `MouseMotionListener#mouseDragged(...)`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Optional;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Main2 {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    Object columnNames[] = {"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"};
    Object data[][] = {
      { "a", "a", "a" },
      { "a", "a", "a" },
      { "a", "a", "a" },
      { "a", "a", "a" },
      { "a", "a", "a" },
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames));
    table.setDragEnabled(true);
    table.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT_ROWS);
    table.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      @Override public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getComponent();
        Optional.ofNullable(c.getTransferHandler())
                .ifPresent(th -> th.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY));
      }
    });
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);

    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(new JScrollPane(table));
    p.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return p;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new Main2().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Selection mode should only be possible via click and should be extendable via shift + click, not via dragging

You may be able to alter the behavior by overriding JTable's `processMouseEvent` method with some additional logic. When a button down event occurs - and shift is not down - alter the selection of the JTable to the current clicked row before calling the parent method.

```
JTable table = new JTable( rowData, columnNames){
    @Override
        public void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e){
            Component c = (Component)e.getSource();
            if (e.getModifiersEx() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK  && ( e.getModifiers() & MouseEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK) == 0 ){
                int row = rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                int col = columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
                if ( !isCellSelected(row, col) ){
                     clearSelection();
                     changeSelection(row, col, false, false);
                }

            }
            MouseEvent e1 = new MouseEvent(c, e.getID(), e.getWhen(), 
                    e.getModifiers() | InputEvent.CTRL_MASK, 
                    e.getX(), e.getY(), 
                    e.getClickCount(), 
                    e.isPopupTrigger() , 
                    e.getButton());

            super.processMouseEvent(e1);
        }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't work in all cases. It doesn't work if you are e. g. in single cell selection mode. I updated the example with the single cell selection mode. I've seen solutions with overriding of processMouseEvent. I haven't found one yet that works satisfactory.

Comment: @Roland, there may not be an easier answer than to just implement it on a selection mode basis...that being said Control initiates a drag - Shift should have priority. So you could alter the selections as necessary, then pass a MouseEvent with control mask (see edit - note I have not tested this for all selection modes).

Comment: thank you very much for your effort. But now the selection of a single cells is gone. When I click on a cell, it only gets the focus border. I'll toy around with your solution. But as I said, I've seen that solution before. What I don't like about it is the changing of the selection which implicitly invokes some listeners. I'm searching more for a proper way without side effects.